# How can I save any changes on my github website when made changes from diffrent devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, web

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<title>Who is working on the table</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>


<ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox" value="yes"> Alex is working on the table.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox3" value="yes"> Tom is working on the table.</li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="mycheckbox2" value="yes"> Lisa is working on the table.</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- This JavaScript file is required to load the XpressDox interview as well as the code required to run it -->

<script>
// Avoid scoping issues by encapsulating code inside anonymous function
(function() {
  // variable to store our current state
  var cbstate;

  // bind to the onload event
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Get the current state from localstorage
    // State is stored as a JSON string
    cbstate = JSON.parse(localStorage['CBState'] || '{}');

    // Loop through state array and restore checked
    // state for matching elements
    for(var i in cbstate) {
      var el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + i + '"]');
      if (el) el.checked = true;
    }

    // Get all checkboxes that you want to monitor state for
    var cb = document.getElementsByClassName('save-cb-state');

    // Loop through results and ...
    for(var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {

      //bind click event handler
      cb[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        // If checkboxe is checked then save to state
        if (this.checked) {
          cbstate[this.name] = true;
        }

    // Else remove from state
        else if (cbstate[this.name]) {
          delete cbstate[this.name];
        }

    // Persist state
        localStorage.CBState = JSON.stringify(cbstate);
      });
    }
  });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code shows 3 checkboxes. I want to save changes made from any location and devices. For example Alex checked the first box, I want to edit the table, but I that Alex is working on it. After he finished Alex unchecks the box and I refresh the page, so that i can see Alex is done with his work...

Comment: You will need some kind of server side code to save that information

Comment: what kind of server? can you explain futher

Comment: Suppose I'm using your site and I check one item. The item checked doesn't leave my device right? If you refresh you cannot see I have checked because data from my device never left. You should use something like firebase or so to save the data and then retrieve it from there

Comment: i understand what you mean.thank you.

Comment: Am I right? Is it what you wanted?

Comment: yes. i did not know that i have to use firebase or other stuff. so its impossible to make it without any additional tools